# How can I run my node js script automatically using scheduler on server

Tags: node.js, linux, server, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have created a nodejs file using **express** enviornment and running the file on server using **nodemon**. Currently I have to give commands to the interface to run the particular file on nodemon but what I currently need is to schedule the task to run that file on server automatically at multiple occasion in a single day.

my file excute like this on terminal::

```
nodemon example_api.js
```

output terminal:

```
    root@*********:/var/www/example project# nodemon example_api.js
[nodemon] ##.##.#####
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node api.js`
Listening on port 8080
```

**Note: I am currently running node js on Mobaxterm terminal currently using windows but my file will be run on a server with linux interface**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1. If you want to run your node process continuously and want to run only particular task:**

Use [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) or [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) packages to run your code block at desired time or interval.

**i.node-schedule**

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/30 * * * * ', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

**ii.node-cron**

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('*/30 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

**2. If you want to run only single node script:**

You can use Linux crontab to execute your script at desired time

```
crontab -e
```

and add following entry

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/node /home/ridham/example/script.js
```

This will execute `/home/ridham/example/script.js` every 30 minutes. and always give full qualified path here.

You have to give crontime in any of the following. you can learn about crontime [here](https://crontab.guru)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple implementation - you can just use `setInterval` like so:

```
setInterval(() => {
    // do something every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

But it you want something like a cron, then, you might wanna go with [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) or [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).

You can also use providers like AWS CloudWatch. AWS CloudWatch allows you to run AWS Lambda functions on a cron.